# Regular Expressions + Separate string with no white space

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to write a pattern that can match to both "3Z10Z" and "3Z 10Z", and then return "3Z". (Later I will write the pattern to return the 10Z part...).

I tried using something like  `@"\d+Z\s*\B"` to try and grab the first part, but no dice. One thought I have, if its possible, is for it to read left to right and return the first @"\d+Z" it finds. To later get the "10Z" part I would need it to read from right to left though...

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `@"(\d[A-Z])\s*(.*)"` ?

If you run the program below you can capture both the **prefix** and **suffix** in one shot

Basically a digit followed by upper case letter.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text1 = "3Z10Z";
            string text2 = "3Z 10Z";
            string pattern = @"(\d[A-Z])\s*(.*)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(text1, pattern);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("prefix {0} suffix {1}.", 
                  match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
            }

            match = Regex.Match(text2, pattern);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("prefix {0} suffix {1}.", 
              match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic regular expression that would match is:

```
/(\d+Z)\s*?([^ ]+)/
```

back-reference 1 contains your \d+Z, while back-reference 2 contains your second string. (10Z in your example).  This site explains regular expressions specific to C# http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html.  Let me know if you need any help capturing/ using your back-references.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want to do :

Probably:

```
 (\d+[a-zA-Z])\s*\(d+[a-zA-Z])
```

Is what you meant? $1 and $2 have your parts.

Comment: Yea, suppose it is a bit confusing. Basically I am trying to seperate "3Z10Z" and in one line of code get:
1) string matchOne = "3Z" (using \d+[a-zA-Z])
and in the next line of code
2) string matchTwo = "10Z"